# Windows application running as background process invoke by Windows service via batch file

Tags: c#, .net, background-process, windows

I have a windows application which is invoke in two different away.

1) When someone directly clicks the exe.

2) When windows service is invoke it by a batch file.

The issue that I am facing is, when someone directly clicks on exe, the process got open inside the **Apps** section as a normal process as shown below with its UI:

[image]

When Windows service invoke it by a batch file the process comes under **Background process** and no UI shown in this case

[image]
[image]

I want to invoke the application as a normal process in both cases.

Comment: Your service is not running on the same desktop as the logged in user; and it is not possible anymore... You should use some messaging between your service and an application that could stay in your tray that could handle the message and start the application...

Comment: What type of messaging and how can I handle it?

Comment: Any type :) Windows Message, call to a web service, if the application in the tray is a webservice host. I have no sample to show you.

Comment: Bear in mind that windows has been a multi-user OS for quite a long time. As such, there isn't *a* desktop - there may be *zero* logged in users, a single logged in user or *multiple* logged in users. You need to work out what should happen for each scenario (e.g. should a separate instance of the application run in each user's desktop? If no-one is currently logged in, should the application not be launched at all, or wait for a login to occur? If only a single user should see the app, how should they be selected, etc)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the reply. You are right multiple logged in user are allowed, but only one particular user allow to run that exe and this exe is also invoked by the bath file via windows service. Because of this multiple instances are running and we want only one instance to run in every case